# In Java / Spring is there a way to deprecate the usage of an (undeprecated) annotation?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

In our spring application we have a lot of usage of the `@Resource` (`javax.annotation.Resource`) which per our project conventions we want to replace with explicit Spring getter/setter and `Required` (`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required`) and an xml configuration.

So basically something like this:

```
@Resource
private MyBean myBean;
```

will be replaced with:

```
private MyBean myBean;
[...]

protected MyBean getMyBean()
{
    return myBean;
}

@Required
public void setMyBean(final MyBean myBean)
{
    this.myBean = myBean;
}
```

and in the corresponding `spring.xml` file we would add:

```
<bean id="someBean" .... >
    [...]
    <property name="myBean" ref="myBean" />
    [...]
</bean>
```

(Not asking whether this is a good approach btw :) )

Now for backwards compatibility (as third parties are using our software) we ideally want to "deprecate" the usage of the `@Resource` annotation and indicate to users of our software to add the xml configuration if they extend our beans.
(I also know that normally *if* someone extends our bean they should not only extend the java class but also add a `parent="someBean"` to inherit the properties).
Is there a way in the code to mark the usage of @Resource as deprecated?

Comment: Clients might use `@Resource` to inject other resource types, not your beans. So, the options are limited. You can print warning messages to system output if it's acceptable.

Comment: @Sebastian I wonder if checker framework can do that..

Comment: @defaultlocale not sure I fully understood: We want to basically inform implementers/developers using our code that they should no longer rely on `@Resource`.. so ideally its not a runtime message, but a compiler warning or something alike.

Comment: @Eugene good tip. thanks! I'll take a look at that